# Declaring a variable in python with the name 'class'

Tags: python, class, variables, python-3.6

I'd like to declare a variable (string, in this case) as such:

```
class = "this is my string"
```

In Python **(3.6.3)**, and I get an error:

```
class = "This is my string"
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It obviously doesn't like the fact that I'm using an equal sign (`=`) after `class`.

Let's say I really need to have a variable with the name `class`, and I can't change it to `myClass` or whatsoever, what would be the correct way of doing something as such?

Comment: just don't do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thankfully Python doesn't allow you to do this, `class` is a keyword that can't be used as an identifier. One alternative also mentioned in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) is using a trailing underscore:

```
class_ = ...
```

but you really should avoid such names since they *mostly* serve to confuse. You should always strive for more descriptive ones.

If `class` is the only option, the other (somewhat) viable approach would be to use a dictionary:

```
>>> names = {'class': 'something'}
>>> names['class']
'something'
```

Comment: Got it! Thought perhaps there's a library or something that could potentially do this, hence I asked. I'm quite new to Python! Nevertheless, thanks heaps :)

Comment: @Sina Most languages don't allow you to use reserved keywords as variable names. This has nothing to do with libraries or Python.

Comment: @deceze,"**most** languages", you said. Exactly :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that, as it explicitly stated in the Python documentation:

[image]

[link to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, however it is some kind of a tradition in Python to append class _ to get a new identifier

Use like this:

```
class_ = "This is my string"
```

You can [read Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare reserved words as variables.